# Variance of values that $x_1$ gets in the solutions of $x_1+x_2+...+x_k = n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, variance

I know that the there are ${n-1}\choose{k-1}$ solutions for the equation $x_1+x_2+...+x_k = n$ which all $x_i\ge 1$, is there any way to calculate the variance of the values that $x_1$ gets$?

Comment: $E[x_1] = E[x_2] = \cdots = E[x_k]$ and $E[x_1 + \cdots + x_k] = n$.

Comment: @achillehui Oh! you're right, that was so easy, thank you

Comment: @achillehui Sorry, can you please help me, can I do this for the variance of $x_1$?

Comment: Variance is $\frac{n(n-k)(k-1)}{k^2(k+1)}$.

Comment: @achillehui Can you please a little explain about it, I tried to simplify the answer (below), but I couldn't, I would be so thankful if you help me.

Comment: I obtain the variance by a different method (generating function). Unless you have learned generating function before. it is pretty tedious to describe the set up and make the approach understandable.

Comment: @achillehui thanks, I don't know about generating functions, many thanks to you four your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X_1,\dots,X_k$ to be a random vector uniformly distributed on the solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_k=n$ among positive integers. The probability that $X_1=x$ for $x=1,\dots,n-(k-1)$ is the number of solutions to $X_2+\dots+X_k=n-x$ divided by the total number of solutions. So this is $\frac{{n-x-1 \choose k-2}}{{n-1 \choose k-1}}$. So noting that the mean is just $n/k$ by symmetry, the variance is

$$\sum_{x=1}^{n-(k-1)} \frac{x^2 {n-x-1 \choose k-2}}{{n-1 \choose k-1}} - (n/k)^2.$$

I'll leave the simplification of that sum to you.